# Django REST Framework - How to encrypt the passwords from PUT and PATCH?

Tags: django, rest, http, encryption, django-rest-framework

Currently any password that I PUT or PATCH do not get encrypted.

I am using a ModelSerializer.

```
class UserSerializer (serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'pk')
```

With a ModelViewSet

```
class UserViewSet (ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

Why are my passwords saved as plain text? And how do I fix this?

Should I overwrite the update () in serialiser or update () in ViewSet? Where's the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should overwrite `create` and `update` methods in your `serializers` to make encryption possible:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            password=make_password(
                validated_data['user'].pop('password')
            ),
            **validated_data.pop('user')
        )

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if 'user' in validated_data:
            instance.user.password = make_password(
                validated_data.get('user').get('password', instance.user.password)
            )
            instance.user.save()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'url', 'username', 'email', 'pk'
        )
```